# How can get value form two input using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two input field :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-td" name="getmark[]" id="getMark_<?php echo $i++?>"  required>
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-td" name="mcq[]" id="mcq_<?php echo $i++?>" required>
```

*I am trying :*

```
 $('input[id^="getMark_"]','input[id^="mcq_"]').on('change', function() {  
       var get_mark = this.value;
       var mcq      = this.value;

 });
```

i am not sure how can call  `$('input[id^="getMark_"]','input[id^="mcq_")`

How can call two input filed .

Comment: try with classname, this id method looks messy,  **$('.form-control input-td:nth-chile(1)','form-control input-td:nth-chile(1)').on('change', function() {**

Comment: i have many student data . so i need check  `getMark & mcq ` input  field .this student pass or fail of this subject

Comment: did you try to select element by name *$('td[name=name]')*

Comment: You are not closing your second input properly. You forgot a '... Try like this: $('input[id^="getMark_"]','input[id^="mcq_"').on('change', function() {

Comment: @mindmaster . you say right but code not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error and input is a proper event for your situation

```js
$('input[id^="getMark_"], input[id^="mcq_"').on('input', function() {  
  var mark = mcq = '';
    if($(this).attr("id").indexOf('getMark_') !== -1){
      mark = this.value;
    }else{
     mcq = this.value
    }
  console.log(mark,mcq);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-td" name="getmark[]" id="getMark_<?php echo $i++?>"  required>
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-td" name="mcq[]" id="mcq_<?php echo $i++?>" required>
```

It will get the change in the input textbox.

Comment: Your code work . Just change  `.on('input'` to  `on('change ,`

Comment: Either way worked. You can take your call as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

For your code that will work:

```
$(document).on('change','input[id^=getMark_], input[id^=mcq_]', function() {  
       var get_mark = this.value;
       var mcq = this.value;
 });
```

So you don't need "" or '' inside attribute selector...
But you have also logical error your get_mark and mcq variable will be always the same.

So you need two separate methods to get those variables, that would be better choise

```
$(document).on('change','input[id^=getMark_]', function() {  
           var get_mark = this.value;
     });

$(document).on('change','input[id^=mcq_]', function() {  
           var get_mark = this.value;
     });
```

If you need you can save them to global variables.

Comment: i need check two input value tin real time . that this student pass or fail

Comment: Then you need to have some Submit button where you get and check those values at one...

Comment: i have two input field  `mcq & getMark` i need to check every mark pass or fail . if pass or fail then result show other input field

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like**

```js
 $(' input[name="getmark[]"], input[name="mcq[]"] ').on('change', function() {  
       var get_mark = $('input[name="getmark[]"]').val();
       var mcq      = $('input[name="mcq[]"]').val();
       
       console.log('get_mark', get_mark);
       console.log('mcq', mcq);

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-td" name="getmark[]" id="getMark_<?php echo $i++?>"  required>
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-td" name="mcq[]" id="mcq_<?php echo $i++?>" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your html by :

```
  <div id='student_<?php echo $student_id; //$i++; ?>' class='student'>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-td" class="getmark" name="getmark[]"    id="getMark_<?php echo $i++?>"  required>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-td"  class="mcq"  name="mcq[]" id="mcq_<?php  echo $i++?>" required>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-td" class="is_success" readonly>
 </div>
```

Repace your js by :

```
$('.getmark, .mcq').on('change', function() {  
   var get_mark = this.value;
   var mcq      = this.value;
  if(get_mark > 18)
    $(this).find('.is_success').val()='pass';
   else 
     $(this).find('.is_success').val()='fail';
});
```

To collect all of them :

```
function getallstudentmark()
{
arr_allstudents = new Array();

  $(.student).each(function (index, value) {
    obj_student = new Object();
    obj_student.id= $(this).attr('id');
    obj_student.get_mark = $(this).find('.getmark').val();
    obj_student.mcq = $(this).find('.mcq').val();
    obj_student.success = $(this).find('.is_success').val();
    arr_allstudents.push(obj_student);
  });
return arr_allstudents;
}
```